# toString() method behaviour in Objects

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

So I was reading a book of Js and came across this beautiful topic of Object to primitive conversion.
In the book the author says

> For historical reasons, if toString or valueOf returns an object, there’s no error, but such value is ignored (like if the method didn’t exist). That’s because in ancient times there was no good “error” concept in JavaScript.

Now I tried this , but not getting as said in the book:

```
let user = {
    name: "John",
    money: 1000,

   toString(){
       return {
           name: 'Bong'
       };
   }
  };

  alert(user);
```

I got the error in the console saying :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

However, If I do this

```
alert(user.toString());
```

Then there is no erro, It gives [Object object]

Please explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case, `user.toString` is called implicitly because `alert` is expecting a string and `user` is not a string. When `user.toString()` is called and the return value is not a string an error is thrown.

In the second case, `user.toString` is called explicitly by you, it doesn't matter if its name is `toString` or not because it returns the inner object just like any other method would (no primitve value is expected here). The inner object is then passed to `alert`, and its `toString` gets implicitly called which returns a string because it isn't overridden. The second case can be broken into two parts for clarity:

```
let obj = user.toString();    // first user.toString gets called, it will return the inner object
alert(obj);                   // obj.toString will implicitly gets called and since that will return a string everthing will be fine
```

If the inner object has a `toString` that returns an object, then the second case won't work either:

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  money: 1000,

  toString() {
    return {
      name: 'Bong',
      toString() {                  // toString of the inner object is overridden
        return {};                  // ... and it returns an object
      }
    };
  }
};

alert(user.toString());            // now even the second case won't work because when toString of the inner object is called, a string is expected, but instead an object is returned which is a no no
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. Now I got it.

Comment: Sorry but The book says if toString or valueOf returns an object, there’s no error, ?

Comment: I got your point about string , but why does the book says it like there will be no error, is there mistake in book or what

Comment: @Thelostcause `toString` never threw any errors, it's `alert` that throws the error because it cannot show an object, it needs a primitive value.

Comment: @Thelostcause When you do `let obj = user.toString();` it runs without any errors no matter what `toString` returns

Comment: @Thelostcause `alert` can only show a `string` in the dialog box. If `alert` is passed an object, it says: _"ok no problem. I'll just call `toString` of that object and get its string representation and show that instead"_. `toString` is then called successfuly **without any errors** but the return value is not a string. `alert` is now in panic mode, it doesn't know what to do with this object, it throws an error. So technically `toString` never threw an error (even if it did not return a string), it's what called `toString` that threw the error because it expected a string out of it.

Answer (score 0):

`[object Object]` is the default string representation of an object.

When you're calling the object; `toString()` is called on the object, and the initial implementation returns `[object Object]`.

If you want to review the object, you can either review it through `console.log` or through `JSON.stringify()`. You can also loop through all the properties and inspect them individually.

**Example**:

```
const objectOne = {};
const objectTwo = new Object;
const objectThree = {};

objectThree.toString = function () { return "Bong" };

alert(objectOne); // [object Object]
alert(objectTwo); // [object Object]
alert(objectThree); // Bong
```

Answer (score -1):

`alert` does not auto convert non primitives to strings you need the `toString()` method for that. When you call `toString()` on a non primitive you get the default return which is its type and since everything in javascript is essentially an object the default return is `[Object object]`.